# Two of Magento 2 indexers not running on a scheduled cron

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Product categories and Catalog product rule indexes are not running on a scheduled cron. Is this normal?

[image: Magento Indexers]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are couple of things you can check.

1. Check if after changing those indexer into `Update by schedule` mode you can see tables `catalog_category_product_cl` and `catalog_product_category_cl`. If not you need to debug why changing mode is not creating them.
2. Check if triggers that should fill these tables are created with commands in the database: `show triggers where statement like "%catalog_category_product_cl%";` and `show triggers where statement like "%catalog_product_category_cl%";`. When I checked 2.2.6 clean version I see 6 and 9 triggers respectively.
3. Do some changes by editing the category or product and see if `%_cl` tables are updated with ids of the changed entity
4. Check table `cron_schedule` for entries with `job_code` set to `indexer_update_all_views`. See if the result is success or error and if they were actually run.
5. If enabling only them or only 1 of them is working but not with others that could mean some other indexer is causing an error and the processor is not reaching this particular indexer.
6. If you see `Reindex Required` status that means some module marked this indexer as invalid but the `%_cl` tables are probably not updated. This status should be updated by cron `indexer_reindex_all_invalid`. Check `cron_schedule` table if you see it fired and executed without errors.

Comment: If those triggers don't exists, how do I create them?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the indexer mode to **update on schedule** by running the below command

```
php bin/magento indexer:set-mode schedule
```

You can check the mode by running the below command

```
php bin/magento indexer:show-mode
```

You can change the mode to **update on save** by running the below command

```
php bin/magento indexer:set-mode save
```

Refer this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html) for breief explanation regarding indexer command

Comment: I see cache getting invalidated in frequent intervals if I change the indexer mode to update on schedule.